# what will change in a trunk between lacp mode and trunk mode?

Tags: hp-procurve, ieee-802.1ax

I need to link two HP switch with multiple port for throughput purpose.
they are different models but same generation.

I could use either `trunk 37-40 trk1 lacp` or otherwise `trunk 37-40 trk1 trunk` on both side. both config works, I understand it will use lacp or not but what is the difference in performance or throughput or whatever ? is one more performing than the other ?

I may need LACP between servers and workstations, but do I need LACP between switches ?

thanks for your advice.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LACP is a *protocol* where both side negotiate the trunk - if either side doesn't use LACP both (all) links will stay separate. STP may step in and prevent a bridge loop.

A static trunk uses *no protocol*. Once the links are up they are regarded as being trunked, whether or not the other side is set up in the same way.

It's a good idea to use LACP whenever possible to avoid misconfiguration. There is no difference in performance or such.